# failed to make test using uiautomator 2.0

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I want to make uiautomator 2.0 test from the command line. My steps are below:

1. create an Instrumentation project, the code is below:

   ```
   package com.android.uiautomator.client;


   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import android.app.Application;
   import android.app.Instrumentation;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
   import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
   import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
   public class Initialize {

   @Test
   public void testStartServer() {
       System.out.println("this is the test");
   }
   }
   ```
2. use gradlew to generate the test apk
3. install the test apk into the android emulator

   ```
   adb shell push ${apkPath}/test.apk /data/local/tmp/com.android.test

   adb shell pm install -r /data/local/tmp/com.android.test
   ```
4. check if the test apk is installed successfully. And I can find the installed apk.

   ```
   adb shell pm list packages
   ```
5. after install, I check the Instrumentation in the emulator, but I cant't find the Instrumentation about the test apk. This will lead to failed on executing the command:

   ```
   adb shell am instrument -e class com.android.uiautomator.client.Initialize -w com.android.uiautomator.client.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
   ```

so, I am confused. Why can't I find the instrumentation after I have installed the test apk?

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
$ adb shell pm list instrumentation | grep 'target=applicationId'
```

replacing `applicationId` by your applicationId to check the available instrumentations for an app.

Comment: yes, I have tried it. But I still can't find the instrumentation for the installed test apk

Comment: Then, the instrumentation is not installed or is not for that package, remove the grep filter and see all installed